# where is the root page for my website coming from?

Tags: octobercms

I checked out the source code for a website that my company runs with OctoberCMS via Git and got a DB dump and I'm not able to get my local copy of the website looking like the prod copy does.

In the myproject/themes/mytheme/pages directory there are three files:

- home-page.htm
- page1.htm
- page2.htm

home-page.htm has the following:

```
title = "my_home"
url = "/home"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0
==
blah blah blah
```

On my local install /home returns the same content that / does on prod. Here's what / and /home do on both prod and local:

Local:

- /home works
- / returns an error 404

Prod:

- / works (returns the same content as /home on local)
- /home returns an error 404

Why is prod behaving differently than local? The fact that home-page.htm has `url = "/home"` makes me think that local is behaving correctly. So why is prod behaving the way it is then? Where should I be looking to figure this out?

Comment: Maybe you use an ".htaccess" file and redirect in it /home to / ?

Comment: @MatteoDalGrande - here's my .htaccess: https://pastebin.com/HD6wvCZE

Comment: Are you sure that the local version and the production version have the same files and code? Mine it's a silly question but it is important.

Comment: @MatteoDalGrande - pretty sure, yah. The production version is a Docker container. Other websites are hosted on that same container. Whenever an update is made to any of them the container is blown away and a new one built from scratch. Bamboo does the actual deployments and nothing in the scripts there do anything with .htaccess. http://pastebin.com/bwFb9aL9 is the bulk of what it does

Comment: Hence, the docker is hosted on OctoberCMS. Could you build the docker on your machine with the Dockerfile? If the docker produce the same output like the OctoberCMS version We predict that the problem is inside the docker, if not maybe is a problem on OctoberCMS settings.
However, I think it's a simple rename of url or redirect of the page.

Comment: @MatteoDalGrande - I _am_ running OctoberCMS inside the Docker container locally. And I'm connecting to the prod DB from the Docker container...

Comment: `/home` returns an error 404 -> that means your `home` file content must be different. some script or something is changing it. there is no other way in production `/home will show 404`. please log in to the backend in the production site and check it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the production server was running https://octobercms.com/plugin/axmit-storage (which stores CMS content in the DB instead of the local FS) whereas the local server wasn't.